# if a folder has a type of file in it or any of its subfolders copy all of its contents

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to clean up some drives that have some 3d models in them. The models are in folders and there are other things in the folders that need to go with the models in order for the models to work. These folders are mixed in with a bunch of unrelated folders. So I want to move a folder and its sub-folders if said folder contains a certain file type. 
So far, I have this.

```
for /d %f in ("C:\in_folder\*") do @if exist "%~f\*.txt" move "%~f" "C:\out_folder"
```

This works great if the file is on the first level of folder (in parent directory). If it is in the second level it doesn't work. I have tried using `/r` and it just comes back blank. 
edit: changed "%~f" to "%~f*.txt". This is what I originally used I
 mistyped it.

Comment: The `FOR /D` option does not list files.  It only lists folders.  So I am not sure how you are checking for files.  If you need to list files recursively then use a `FOR /R`.  If you need to list folders recursively then use `FOR /D /R`

Comment: Suppose your file is in `parent\first\second`. Do you want to move `parent\first` or `parent\first\second` ?

Comment: I want to move parent\first\second if possible.

Comment: @Squashman Aw yeah I mistyped it, I edited it to show the item search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /r %a in (*.3gp) do for %d in ("%~dpa.") do echo md u:\destdir\%~nxd&echo move %~dpa* u:\destdir\%~nxd
```

Note that this line will `echo` the moves required. After testing, remove the `echo` keywords to actually do the `move`.

Note that this is written for direct execution from the prompt as indicated in the question. To use as a batch line, double every `%` to `%%`.

This is expected to be executed where the current directory is the directory to be analysed.

The destination directory will be for instance `fred` if files matching `*.3gp` (for example) exist in `.\fred` and `second` if they exist in `.\first\second`.